# Problem with configuring multiple HttpSecurity instances

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have problem with configuring multiple `httpSecurities`.
I have some api routes that are protected with JWT tokens.

I want my `swagger-ui/index.html` route to be protected with basic auth.
I want those API routes to still be protected with JWT token even after user is authenticated with basic auth.

I followed [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/configuration/java.html#jc-httpsecurity) documetation to create multiple `SecurityFilterChain`s

My problem is whichever `FilterChain` has `@Order(1)` works and other `FilterChain` is completely ignored.
(if `filterChain` has order 1, routes for products and orders are protected, but `swagger-ui/index.html` is not protected with basic auth)

Here is my implementation.

```java
@Bean
@Order(1)
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    http
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    http
        .cors()
            .and()
        .csrf().disable();
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/products").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/api/orders").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll();
    http
        .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(secret, authenticationManager(authConfig)));
    http
        .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(secret), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    return http.build();
}

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain swaggerFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    http
        .requestMatchers()
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/index.html","/v3/api-docs/","/v3/api-docs")
            .authenticated()
            .and()
        .httpBasic();

    return http.build();
}
```

Comment: If you had read your link completly, you would have found the solution: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/configuration/java.html#_multiple_httpsecurity, see also the other question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use one of the following methods of  `HttpSecurity` at least in one of your filters:
`antMatcher(String)`, `mvcMatcher(String)`, `regexMatcher(String)`, `requestMatcher(RequestMatcher)`, `requestMatchers()`.
This will help you to configure certain `HttpSecurity` to only be invoked when matching the provided patterns.

You've used the last method in the second filter, but did not provide any matchers to the configurer.
So, try to rewrite your second filterChain like this:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain swaggerFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
            .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/swagger-ui/index.html","/v3/api-docs/","/v3/api-docs")
            .and()
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();

    return http.build();
}
```

Also mind that your `swaggerFilterChain` might be invoked first if you don't want to harcode all other endpoints' urls in the other filter chain - if a request matches a filter with first order it will be the only filter to be applied, so others will be ignored.
So you also need to change the order - place `@Order(1)` to your `swaggerFilterChain` and remove this annotation from the other filter chain.

Comment: You are a LIFE SAVER!!! I've spent almost two days bashing my head on this same problem and the requestMatchers() method at the start of the chain is what solved it for me, as well. Thanks to both you and OP for putting this out here.

Answer (score 0):

try this, move `.antMatchers("/api/**")` to the beginning like the [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/configuration/java.html#_multiple_httpsecurity)

```java
@Bean
@Order(1)
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
    http.antMatchers("/api/**")
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/products").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/api/orders").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().permitAll();
    http.addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(secret, authenticationManager(authConfig)));
    http.addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(secret), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);


    return http.build();
}
```

Comment: Your answer makes no sense, because there is no method `antMatchers` on `HttpSecurity `.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for trying to help. Problem was solved by other answer. After i got multiple filter chains to work i tried your suggestion to check if it would change anything. Working solution actually stopped working when i placed antmatcher("/api/**") to begining